# Outlook MailItem runtime error 287 on replacing text in message body

Tags: vba, outlook

I am creating an Outlook 2010 message from a template (oft file) and replacing part of the text within the Subject, Body and To properties.

When I read Body and To a runtime error 287 is raised.

```
Sub test()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Public\JobsTracker.V01\Templates\Template-1.oft")
    olItem.Subject = Replace(olItem.Subject, "sometext", "othertext") 'This works
    olItem.Body = Replace(olItem.Body, "sometext", "othertext")       'This raises Runtime Error 287
    olItem.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: did you ever get this working? I ahve same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try moving olItem.Display

```
Sub test()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Public\JobsTracker.V01\Templates\Template-1.oft")

    olItem.Display

    olItem.Subject = Replace(olItem.Subject, "sometext", "othertext") 'This works
    olItem.Body = Replace(olItem.Body, "sometext", "othertext")
End Sub
```

If that does not work. Looks like the code is not in Outlook since you are using

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Try Shell "Outlook.exe" before running the code then

```
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
```

You may have to set up a delay until Outlook opens.

Answer (score 0):

In certain circumstances, Outlook may not be fully functional with

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Details here [NameSpace.Logon Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861594%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

"...first, instantiate the Outlook Application object, then reference a default folder such as the Inbox. This has the side effect of initializing MAPI to use the default profile and **to make the object model fully functional.**"

```
Sub InitializeMAPI ()

    ' Start Outlook.
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Get a session object. 
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Create an instance of the Inbox folder. 
    ' If Outlook is not already running, this has the side
    ' effect of initializing MAPI.
    Dim mailFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set mailFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Continue to use the object model to automate Outlook.
End Sub
```